# How make logger with saving all app logs in Room? (in Runtime)

Tags: android, logging, android-room

Please, I need help and I broken my head! ((
How make logger with permanently saving logs when app is running?
Is it possible to do this without third-party libraries?

**UPDATE:**
That's what I did

```
 class AppLogger(private val context: Context, private val db: AppDatabase) : KoinComponent,
    ContextWrapper(context) {

    @SuppressLint("WorldWriteableFiles", "BinaryOperationInTimber")
    suspend fun internalSaveFile() {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            //-d emulator, -s real device
            val process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("logcat -d -v threadtime")
            val bufferedReader = BufferedReader(
                InputStreamReader(process.inputStream)
            )
            var line: String? = null
            var counter = 0

            while ({ line = bufferedReader.readLine(); line }() != null) {
                if (line != "--------- beginning of main") {

                    val timeFromLogs = line?.substring(0, 18)
                    var priorityTag = ""

                    var t = 0// index to start cutting messages from logs
                    val l = line?.length?.minus(1)
                    for (i in 1..l!!) {
                        if (i > 18) {
                            val q = line?.get(i)
                            if (q == ':') {
                                t = i
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    val messageLog = line?.substring(t + 2)
                    val saveLogs = AppLoggerEntity(
                        counter++, priorityTag, null, null,
                        timeFromLogs, null, null,
                        null, null, message = messageLog
                    )
                    launchSaveInBD(saveLogs)

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun launchSaveInBD(entity: AppLoggerEntity) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            db.appLoggerDao().saveLog(entity)
        }
    }
```

I run it in the Application class, but it only records the logs that appear at the beginning, but do not record anything further.

My DB - init in Koin

```
fun initDatabaseModule(context: Context): Module {
    return module {
        single {
            Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "app-database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build()
        }

        factory { get<AppDatabase>().appLoggerDao() }
    }
}
```

Initializing in Application() class

```
class App : MultiDexApplication() {
    override fun onCreate() {
       super.onCreate()
          initLogger()
          startKoin() {
              //start my loggerModule
    }
    
    private fun initLogger() {
            GlobalScope.launch { 
                AppLogger(this).internalSaveFile()
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm also trying start it in MainActivity with inject from koin, but I get similar trouble

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Please provide more detail about your problem. Generally after reading your question, I'd suggest you to look to monkey patching, but there is a lot of lack of information.

Comment: I'm updated my question

Comment: Better, but please read this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - and try to reformulate your code. It will help other people to reproduce your problem and maybe they can help you.

Comment: I see some edits - very good. I have an another link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask which may lead you to https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm resolve my problem writing custom logger